# AttributeError: 'Third_Window' object has no attribute 'history'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am a beginner and i am trying to do a password saver app. In this i am getting a error like AttributeError: 'Third_Window' object has no attribute 'history'.

And i also want how to Label a text that is inside a file

In .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

Window.clearcolor = 0, 0, 1, 0


class Second_Window(Screen):
    pass


class Third_Window(Screen):
    def btn2(self):
        global history
        file1 = open('users_input.txt', 'r')
        Lines = file1.readlines()
        for line in Lines:
            print("{}".format(line.strip()))
            self.history = ""
            self.history += "{}".format(line.strip())
        print(history)


class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Main_Window(Screen):
    pass


presentation = Builder.load_file("password_saver.kv")


class Password_Saver(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Password_Saver().run()
```

In .kv file

```
Screen_Manager:
    Main_Window:
    Second_Window:
    Third_Window:

<Main_Window>:
    name: 'main'

<Second_Window>:
    name: 'second'

<Third_Window>:
    name: 'third'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: root.history
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                root.btn2()
                app.root.current = 'main'
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure but it may be related to `self.history` not being defined at `__init__`. Yes you did execute `.btn2()`method but `text: root.history` directive maybe trying to access it when you init the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kivy file you are using root.history. `root` in that part of your kv file is third screen. To access something frpm .py file use `app.` instead of `root.`.

Comment: I also used app.history then also it is showing error as  NameError: name 'history' is not defined

Comment: define history at the start of your .py file then call app.history